# Как узнать ресурсоемкость выполняющегося запроса?

Tags: sql-server

В SqlServer Managment Studio есть Activity Monitor, который имеет график использования CPU и список запросов, которые делаются на сервере.

Однако не показывается сколько какой выполняющийся запрос отжирает CPU у сервера.

Есть "Последние ресурсоемкие запросы", но, как я понимаю, туда пишутся запросы, которые завершились.

Можно ли как-нибудь получить данную информацию?

Comment: _"сколько какой выполняющийся запрос"_ запрос всмысле _request_ или всмысле _query_?

Comment: @i-one, речь о query.

Comment: так, а загрузка CPU интересует моментальная (за прошедшую минуту или секунду, например), или суммарная с начала выполнения query?

Comment: @i-one, сколько запрос отжирает CPU в текущий момент времени.

Answer (score 2):

Как то пользовался кодом отсюда: [Find High CPU Query](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/33c7521f-7ed4-4574-82dd-aeb2f32111c5/find-high-cpu-query?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Конкретно этим:

```
      SELECT TOP 50
        [Avg. MultiCore/CPU time(sec)] = qs.total_worker_time / 1000000 / qs.execution_count,
        [Total MultiCore/CPU time(sec)] = qs.total_worker_time / 1000000,
        [Avg. Elapsed Time(sec)] = qs.total_elapsed_time / 1000000 / qs.execution_count,
        [Total Elapsed Time(sec)] = qs.total_elapsed_time / 1000000,
        qs.execution_count,
        [Avg. I/O] = (total_logical_reads + total_logical_writes) / qs.execution_count,
        [Total I/O] = total_logical_reads + total_logical_writes,
        Query = SUBSTRING(qt.[text], (qs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1,
            (
                (
                    CASE qs.statement_end_offset
                        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.[text])
                        ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
                    END - qs.statement_start_offset
                ) / 2
            ) + 1
        ),
        Batch = qt.[text],
        [DB] = DB_NAME(qt.[dbid]),
        qs.last_execution_time,
        qp.query_plan
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.[sql_handle]) AS qt
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
    where qs.execution_count > 5
    ORDER BY [Total MultiCore/CPU time(sec)] DESC
```

И его как правило хватало для решения вопроса производительности. Но как можно заметить, информация о использовании CPU берется из [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189741(v=sql.120).aspx), а в описания на MSDN:

> Возвращает суммарную статистику производительности для кэшированных
>   планов запросов в SQL Server.

То есть эта информация статистистическая.

В старых версиях MS SQL (до 2005) есть таблица [sys.sysprocesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179881(v=sql.120).aspx) и по ней можно получить именно "онлайн" информацию о загрузке CPU.